# Callable type with many possible arguments

Tags: python, mypy

I have some code where a function (`baz` in the code below) consumes another function with can either have signature `Foo -> Any` or `Bar -> Any` where `Foo` and `Bar` are user defined classes.

```py
from typing import Union, Callable, Any

class Foo: ...
class Bar: ...

args = Union[Foo, Bar]

def baz(func: Callable[[args], Any]) -> Any:
    ...

def bax(foo: Foo) -> Any:
    ...

baz(bax)
```

The code works, but mypy complains about the last line, saying

```
Argument 1 to "baz" has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo], Any]"; expected "Callable[[Union[Foo, Bar]], Any]"
```

which makes sense, `Foo -> Any` is not strictly the same as `(Foo | Bar) -> Any`. I can change the typehint for the `func` argument to

```py
def baz(func: Union[Callable[[Foo], Any], Callable[[Bar], Any]]) -> Any:
    ...
```

and mypy is satisfied. This is fine, but my problem is that the `args` type is actually much larger than just `Foo` and `Bar` and hence writing all of these types out by hand would be too cumbersome. Is there a better way of handling this?

As an added layer of complexity, the `func` argument should eventually be able to take functions with signature `Sequence[Foo] -> Any` in addition to `Foo -> Any`.

Comment: You should probably define a `Protocol` subclass (call it `BazProtocol`) that captures what it is about `Foo`, `Bar`, etc that make them suitable as arguments to `baz`, then use `Callable[[BazProtocol], Any]` as the type hint for `func`.

Comment: You almost certainly should not try to support `Foo` and `Sequence[Foo]`. Just support `Sequence[Foo]`, and let the caller provide a singleton list, tuple, etc as an argument.

Comment: I completely agree with @chepner Protocol suggestion, but if you can't for some reason (e.g. some nested isinstance checks you can't control) - perhaps a type alias like `_CT = Callable[[_T], Any]` and then `func: _CT[Foo] | _CT[Bar] | ...` can make you life a bit easier. `TypeVar` solution is a bit hacky (it works, but is not actually using type variables as intended), but clever and perhaps worth the astonishment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to allow mypy to resolve the parameter to `Callable` as being a particular subtype of `Foo | Bar` at each call site:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, Callable, Any

class Foo: ...
class Bar: ...

args = Union[Foo, Bar]

T = TypeVar("T", bound=args)  # New TypeVar

def baz(func: Callable[[T], Any]) -> Any:  # Type hint updated with TypeVar
    ...

def bax(foo: Foo) -> Any:
    ...

baz(bax)
```

Note that will also permit callables that accept any combination of the union members. So, for instance, if `args = A | B | C`, then callables accepting a parameter with any of the following types would pass type checking:

```
Callable[[A], Any]
Callable[[B], Any]
Callable[[C], Any]
Callable[[A | B], Any]
Callable[[A | C], Any]
Callable[[B | C], Any]
Callable[[A | B | C], Any]
```

If you want to only permit either `Foo` or `Bar`, but not `Foo | Bar` as the parameter type, you can explicitly list the allowed types when defining the `TypeVar`. This unfortunately comes at the cost of having to repeat all of the union members instead of referencing the existing union type.

```
TypeVar("T", Foo, Bar)
```

Comment: Ah sweet, I've never had a reason to use `TypeVar`. I guess now I do! I think it will be fine to allow all the subset of combinations as you note at the bottom of your answer, but is there a way to only allow single instances, without the unions?

Comment: @natty It's possible if you're ok with re-listing the union members. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your type describes a single function than take either `Foo` or `Bar` argument. You need to make a union of the two callable types.

```
Ftype = Union[Callable[[Foo], Any], Callable[[Bar], Any]]

def baz (func: Ftype) -> Any:
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah this works, but it gets quite cumbersome once `args` contains more than two types.

Comment: That's true, but that's how the logic works.